# Detect existing OS and add it to system startup list

Tags: multi-boot, operating-systems

I have three partitions: on one partition I have an old OS.

Is there a way to detect an existing OS on a selected partition and then add it to the system startup list (Windows)?

Comment: What version of windows?  Windows XP uses a different boot system than Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Is the old OS a Windows one?

Comment: THi si resolved, I have found software that can do this for me. Works on xp, vista and win 7. Its called EasyBCD 2.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)** is very useful for working with the boot menu, etc.  It is also freeware.

> EasyBCD is geared for users of all kinds. **Whether you just want to add an entry to your old XP partition** or want to create a duplicate for testing purposes; if you're interested in debugging the Windows Kernel or septuple-booting your seven test operating systems, EasyBCD is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Thus I don't know what your "old" operating system is, i suggest you to use a bootloader like grub. If the old system is an older windows version, the newer windows bootloaders (vista, 7) should recognize it and be able to boot it.

Comment: jap I understand, there is system boot menu in windows, and I have windows 7 and I have installed new instance of windows 7 on another partition and it didn't recognized old version, I have found software that can detect os and add record into boot.ini so old os is in system boot screen (windows system selection screen).

Answer (score 0):

THi si resolved, I have found software that can do this for me. Works on xp, vista and win 7. Its called EasyBCD 2.0.2